# Python 2.7.12 Matplotlib x11 forwarding not showing or throwing multiple errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, x11, x11-forwarding

I am logging in to a remote linux machine from windows 7 via putty. In the settings I enabled the X11 forwarding option, and added the -X flag when loging in to the ssh server. On this server I run the following python code:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pyfits
a = raw_input("path: ") #filepath on the server, conected with filename
file = pyfits.open (a +'/file.fits', memap = 'True')
data = file[0].data
print data.shape #shape gets printed correctly

plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(data[0,:,:], cmap = 'gray')
print 3
plt.show()
print 4
```

I get all the print values, with the output looking like this:

```
(300, 512, 512)
3
4
```

there is no error raised nor a x11 window opend. The comadoline goes back as if the program was at the end. Is there any possibility to get the `plt.show()` comand to actually show on the remote controlling windows machine?

Comment: To test if your x11 forwarding is really working you can save your figure with `plt.savefig("out.png")` and then open it for viewing with `eog out.png` if you have "eye of gnome" on the remote machine

Comment: You have asked mpl to use the `'Agg'` backend which does not include a GUI.  If you want to use interactive windows you will need to use one of the GUI connected backends (ex `'Qt4Agg'` or `'tkagg'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out:

at first it is like "tcaswell" said, you can´t use the `'Agg'` backend with interactive windows. This error gets fixed by just deleting the first two lines of code.
The second problem is, that by the `plt.figure(1)` comand a new figure 1 is created but in the `plt.show()` comand there is no figure specified that should show up. So this error can be solved by either deleting the line that says `plt.figure(1)` or by putting the number of the figure to plot in the brackets behind the `plt.show()` comand: `plt.show(1)`. By this way it is possible to create multiple figures in one file and being able to switch between them.